# Meaning of <$> notation

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I see the <$> notation often in the Plutus/Haskell code but have no idea what it means. I understand that $ alone is a parenthesis replacement. Is <$> similar? Does it suggest enclosing parenthesis?

Example from the deploy.hs script in week 3.

> ```
> dataToScriptData :: Data -> ScriptData
> dataToScriptData (Constr n xs) = ScriptDataConstructor n $ dataToScriptData  xs
> dataToScriptData (Map xs)      = ScriptDataMap [(dataToScriptData x, dataToScriptData y) | (x, y)  xs
> dataToScriptData (I n)         = ScriptDataNumber n
> dataToScriptData (B bs)        = ScriptDataBytes bs
> ```

So hard to do a Google search on Haskell's cryptic syntax!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a functor map which is essentially an fmap function for the functor class. This might be of some use: https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/operators/

Comment: Hoogle is also a great resource for searching Haskell's syntax. https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E (edit: Oh I see your link immediately references Hoogle haha)

Answer (score 3):

For Haskell questions of this sort [Hoogle](https://hoogle.hackage.org/) is the ultimate resource.

For operators like `<$>` you need to enclose them in parenthesis eg `(<$>)`.